# What font is being used by the OS X text application named Brackets

Tags: font-identification, osx, interface-design

I really don't have an eye for this. Can someone identify this font please:

[image: Brackets partial screenshot]

It is a menu of the OSX app named Brackets - i think this font looks awesome but i can't with certainty seem to identify it.

Comment: convert the font into on object and check out the font at http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Mac applications come with their own fonts, you can often find these within the application package (which is technically just a folder): Right-click on the application icon within the Applications folder and choose `Show Package Contents`. A new Finder window containing subfolders will open. Instead of rummaging each and every subfolder for the font files, use the search field of the window: type in ttf, ttc, or otf and choose to search within the current folder (e.g. 'Brackets.app').

In the case of Brackets, it's the **Source Sans Pro** family (and Source Code Pro) by Paul D. Hunt, released as open-source ware by Adobe. The font covers a lot of characters (1107 in version 1.050), and also offers a number of glyph options via OpenType features, e.g., style variants of the letters 'l' and 'g' (open or two-storeyed), old-style figures, small capitals, etc.

Download via SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/files/ Font info at Adobe: http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontPackage&code=1959

Source Sans Pro is also in Google Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like Trebuchet MS, but the 'g' has a closed loop. I did a search in Google Fonts and Open Sans looks a lot like it:

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

But the O seems a little thicker than your sample.

I'd definitely say its a humanist font.

Answer (score 0):

I think calibri is close taking into consideration the form of the letter G, i think you should give it a try:)